# WSO2 EI6.6 : Send email with attachment and HTML body

Tags: html-email, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to send an email with attachment from WSO2EI6.6. The code is working as expected when I tried with some text as email body. When I tried to send HTML content, it is not working as expected. The HTML code is for a table and I am expecting to see the table in email body but the HTML code is displayed in email body as text.

**Sequence**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="EmailSend_SEQ" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">$1</ns:text>
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('emailBodyWithRec')"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <property value="Sample Email" name="Subject" scope="transport" type="STRING"/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="default" type="STRING" value="text/html"/>
    <property name="transport.mail.Format" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="Attachment"/>
    <property expression="get-property('sAttachmentFileName')" name="AttachmentFile" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
    <header expression="fn:concat('mailto:', get-property('primaryEmail'))" name="To" scope="default"/>
    <call/>
    <property name="OUT_ONLY" scope="default" type="STRING" value="false"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <EmailNotificationResponse>
                <Status xmlns="">SUCCESS</Status>
            </EmailNotificationResponse>
        </format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
</sequence>
```

**HTML Content :**

```
<html xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <head>
      <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/><style>table, td, th {   border: 1px solid black;}table {  text-align: center;    border-collapse: collapse;   font-weight:bold}td { width: 140px;}</style></head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th>Transactions Processed</th>
            <td>1111110</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Success</th>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Expired</th>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Failed</th>
            <td>0</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What messageFormater are you using for text/html? For me is working `class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"`

Comment: I am using `<messageFormatter class="org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ApplicationXMLFormatter" contentType="text/html"/>`

Comment: Try removing "transport.mail.bodyWhenAttached" and send the body through payload factory or any other transformation mediators.

Comment: Hi @PrabakaranThodithotSembiyan I  tried that way and updated the code here. Still it is not working

Comment: @HarikrishnanA - The tag <ns:text> makes the message as a text message, so change it to any <html> and pass your property inside it. Alternatively, you can directly use XSLT/Xquery mediator to frame your html body and send the email.